# How do you guard against hidden overflows

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages, language-agnostic, arithmetic

consider the following:

```
(i+j)/2
```

i and j are both 32 bit integers and the result should also be.
But in the little equation, there's a hidden overflow, i+j could become larger then a 32 bit integer even though the result would always be a 32 bit integer.

```
public class Sum{
     public static void main(String []args){
        int i = 2147483647;
        int j = 2147483647;                       
        System.out.println((i + j)/2);
     }
}
```

Gives me -1 as a result.

How do you guard against situations that can overflow but are not always obvious.
Is there a pattern that describes this?

(apart from declaring everything long)

I'm looking for a general answer, the java example is just to  provide an example, my Delphi does the same.

Comment: Guard? You mean, as in "prevent this from happening?" Then how would you ever use the `+` operator? Using `long` only shifts the problem to the next level. You always risk overflow unless you establish your own data types with half the language-provided range.

Comment: @KilianFoth You don't need your own data type, just your own math operators that check for overflow. You could argue that nothing's forcing you to use the non-overflow version, but I'd retort that nothing forces you to use your custom numeric types either.

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot that you can write your own `+` in C++ (because I haven't used it professionally).

Comment: In many cases, you don't need any guards, because the inputs are naturally restricted to a range that won't overflow.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau the immediate reason why I came up with this question was because of an equation that calculated an average price by adding all products sold in a year, dividing that by the number of products, a trivial equation, until you get a customer with over 21 Million in revenue and you get all kinds of weird results.

Comment: @PieterB: luckily I said many, not most or all. GDR ;-)

Comment: In case you haven't changed it yet, your mean value calculator doesn't need to use large intermediate values. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1346937/1734730). To stray from  language-agnosticism, C#'s [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) is related to this and 28 million is no sweat for its [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/364x0z75.aspx) type.

Comment: As @NathanCooper one option is to use an arbitrary-precision decimal or integer type if available. Performance will be lower, so one must make sure this is an acceptable tradeoff. These types are really good when dealing with very large numbers that must also be precise, or when primitive overflow cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

You have three choices, none of which are ideal for all situations:

**Detect Overflows.**  Most languages have a way to determine the largest possible value for integer data types.  The addition in your example will result in an overflow whenever `j > (max_value_of_type - i)`.  You will have to check every use for overflows or build a library or class to does it for you.

**Use Larger Types.**  If there are larger integers available, use those to do your intermediate calculations and convert back to the smaller type when finished.  The hitch here is that you must understand whether the results of those calculations are guaranteed to fit the smaller size if that's what you'll be returning.  Your example of `(i + j) / 2` fits, but `(i * j) / 2` doesn't.

**Restrict the Input Values.**  This is a lot like both of the above in that you're limiting the inputs to values you know won't cause an overflow and at the same time making the integers large enough to hold the result.

Comment: How about the python way? Integers are as large as they need to be to fit the number, no overflow possible. That surely costs a lot of run time, but you should still add it as an option.

Comment: @nwp:  Arbitrary precision falls under the heading of using larger types.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own arithmetic operators, for example like this.

```
int operator + (int a, int b) {
    int res = a + b;
    if(a > 0 && b > 0 && res < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticOverflowException();
    } else if(a < 0 && b < 0 && res > 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticUnderflowException();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: if b or a is 0 the answer may be negative otherwise the answer must be positive?

Comment: Yep, you got me there. The condition must be more clever. :)

Comment: Note: In C/C++ signed overflow is undefined behavior, so you must test for overflow *before* adding. You can do something like this: `if (a > INT_MAX - b) { /* handle overflow */ }`.

Comment: What language is this? It looks like C++ to me, but C++ does not allow defining operators on built in data types only, so you would need to define your own data type `Int`.

Comment: Updated the solution to handle also negative numbers. This is not some particular language, just pseudocode. One would have to adapt it to the language of use.

Comment: Programmers is [about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) conceptual questions and answers are [expected to _explain_ things](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer). Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: @gnat okay, got it. I've just answered the actual question, and, in all honesty, I believe in explaining things through code. It's usually less wordy and more precise than human language. But you have point, and I'll try to give better answers going forward. It's my 2nd day on Programmers. :)

Comment: @Haspemulator using code is fine, but it helps to explain _what_ the code is doing and _why_.